# Repeatedly dividing a magnet into halves

Tags: electromagnetism, matter

Suppose I have bar magnet and I cut it into two halves, then each of these two halves has its own north and south poles. If I continue to perform this action on each of the parts, continuously breaking each successive half into two halves, each of them would still have their own north and south poles.

Can I repeat this process forever, and if so, would I ever reach a situation in which one of the resulting "pieces" does not have a *pair* of north and south poles?

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE. One of the reasons your question has so many downvotes is probably because you used a lot of CAPS in the original, which is often seen as "shouting" on sites like this, and hence considered rude. I have modified your question, while keeping the spirit intact, feel free to reword it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I repeat this process forever,

The answer is no.

There are two ultimate sources of localized magnetic fields:

1. Current loops
2. Smaller objects with magnetic moments

If general your bar magnet will be composed of microscopic versions of both (1) and (2).

The case (1) refers to electric charges moving in some kind of closed orbit (a closed wired or some electrons moving about the nucleus of an atom). If you repeatedly cut your magnet and you discover that there are small permanent current loops that create your magnet, then when you get to the point where you have to cut the loop in half, you will break the current and you will no longer have a magnet (Unless you get into case 2).

Case (2) refers to the idea that there are smaller magnets (the property of producing a magnet like field is called a magnetic moment). If your magnet is composed of smaller magnets, it is ok to think that at some point you will reach the smallest magnet. This is indeed what ultimately happens! When you cut down matter all the way to the subatomic particles, you are left with electrons, protons and neutrons. All of these particles have a permanent magnetic moment that is intrinsic (the proton and the nucleus are composed of quarks, but then quarks also have this property).

Conclusion: Cutting the magnets down will produce two new magnets until you reach some specific point where you do not have any magnetic moment anymore or you will reach elementary particles (the smallest magnets possible).